# "Global" model in NSDocument-based application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsdocument

I have a `NSDocument` based application, which allows the user to send messages, after he has logged in.

These should be the user's steps:

- The user starts the App and logs in (credentials are stored in the user model)
- The user user sends the first message
- The user hits `CMD + N` and sends another message (without having to log in again)

The message model is placed in the `MyDocument.xib`. However the user model should be place in a global place (I would say MainMenu.xib).

My question is now:

1. Does it make sense to put the model in the MainMenu.xib and how can I access it from `MyDocument.m`
2. Is there maybe a better way to do this properly without having to make a singleton class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an NSApplication delegate and then add you functionality in you delegate or an property of you delegate, you can then use [[NSApplicaton sharedApplicaton] delegate] to get you delegate. You application delegate is the place to associate model data that is common to you application.

Comment: Hmm I tried this but the delegate also seemed to be of the type NSApplication, rather than the delegate class I created. Also I do not understand, why the delegate, even if it is not defined, should be of the type `NSApplication`

Comment: It shouldn't be if type NSApplicaton, it should be of type id<UIApplicationDelegate>, you then have to cast it to you type, for example `MyDelegate *delegate = (MyDelegate*)[[NSApplicaton sharedApplicaton] delegate];`. It sounds like you are subclassing NSApplication not adding a delegate, there is a method of NSApplicaton (-[NSApplicaton delegate]) you can even initialise you delegate in the main nib and then connect it to the -[NSApplicaton delegate] in the nib file, that way you delegate is available as soon as your main nib is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working with my NSApplication subclass (some say this is not the way to go). For this I had to change the principal class from `NSApplication` to my new custom NSApplication subclass.

Comment: Nathan's option now also worked so now I am using an Application Delegate.